# What are the security implications of sp_executesql?

Tags: sql-server, security, permissions

By default, in SQL Server, the `[public]` role has `EXECUTE` rights on `sp_executesql`.

However, I've inherited a database server where the previous DBA has revoked the `EXECUTE` right on `sp_executesql`.

As a temporary workaround, I've been granting `EXECUTE` rights to `sp_executesql` on an as-needed basis (through a role in the master database). But this is beginning to be a maintenance pain.

If I grant `EXECUTE` back to public, are there any repercussions I need to be aware of?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

None. `sp_executesql` executes SQL, under exactly the same context and privileges as the original caller would execute the *same* SQL. There are many, many, cases when dynamic SQL is unavoidable.

Comment: -1 because the answer does not indicate that microsoft notes that there can be a security risk http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @miracle173 - To be fair it is badly written dynamic SQL that is the security risk not `sp_executesql`. Assuming a dynamic SQL requirement then disabling `sp_executesql` might actually increase the risk as at least that allows you to parameterise the queries (unlike `EXEC`)

Comment: While the risk of sql injection can never be underestimated, disabling `sp_executesql` is not the appropriate mitigation. The overwhelming majority of SQL injection errors occur in the client when the SQL statement is build 'by hand' by concatenating pieces of SQL with input variables and then executes 'as is'. For all those cases `sp_executesql` being disabled helps nothing.